# How was Stack Overflow built?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, architecture

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What was Stack Overflow built with?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with)

What was used for building StackOverflow?

Comment: see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with

Comment: What would be the SO family without its own variant of "where site come from", coming back regularly :-]

Comment: But still, how are baby made?

Comment: @alex: I think you mean "how is babby formed?".

Comment: @alex - All I know is that it takes 6 to 8 weeks.

Comment: It only takes one month if you have nine women.

Comment: @Ether, I have 90 women

Comment: Poorly worded dupes at least allow for some fun in constructing synonymistic nodes. @dow

Comment: ok @ran, I'll leave them alone in the future, I was bored =)

Answer (score 0):

StackOverflow is developed with ASP.NET MVC, C# 3.5 and saves data into SQL Server 2008.

And no, it's not some OpenSource wiki engine, not yet.

Comment: It's also unlikely to be released as Open Source in the medium term, as it is available as a service from FogCreek as the StackExchange product

Answer (score 0):

No, it's specifically developed.